# Debian Bookworm: Install Python after PEP 668

Tags: apt

I have basic Debian `bookworm` and/or `sid` images. I would like to install Python in these using `apt`. Even a simple `apt install python3` does fail saying

```
error: externally-managed-environment
× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
```

I do understand the issue and I am familiar with PEP 668. I am still under the impression that first I should install Python, in order to get a Python interpreter into my images. How do I make `apt` install Python from the Debian repository?

Comment: `apt install python3` works for me; the “externally-managed-environment” error is a `pip` error, it shouldn’t show up during installation of the interpreter. Could you show exactly what commands you’ve run leading up to this?

Comment: @StephenKitt omg you are right. My output got gobbled and it is actually `get-pip.py` that apparently calls itself and through this triggers the error. I never noticed. Thank you!